# How to fix chrome certificate issues after removing Fiddler root cert

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, https

I don't know very much about certificates, and I don't want to break anything trying to resolve this - so asking for some suggestions. At some point agreed to let Fiddler install an HTTPS certificate for decrypting traffic. I decided today that I'm getting spammed somewhat when I have Fiddler opened so I decided to find a way to remove this certificate.

I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827901/how-do-you-remove-the-root-ca-certificate-that-fiddler-installs and followed step **1** from the accepted answer. I actually don't quite understand step **2** - in that I'm not sure which certificates to delete.

I've restarted my machine since as per another answer, and what I'm finding is now chrome isn't happy visiting a particular internal site. This site has some certificate issues but I was previously able to bypass this (as are other users). But now I'm stuck visiting it without re-installing the Fiddler certificate.

[image]

Can anyone suggest how I am able to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason of this behavior is explained in Chrome's error message: that website uses HSTS. HSTS enforces more strict certificate policy for the website.

To make Chrome forget HSTS information for this site: <sup>[[source](http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers)]</sup>

1. In the address bar, type `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`
2. Type the domain name in the text field below *Delete domain*
3. Click the *Delete* button.
4. Type the domain name in the text field below *Query domain*
5. Click the *Query* button.
6. Your response should be *Not found*